# Using TextEdit for HTML

Tags: macos, textedit, file-conversion, html

Is there a way to open a HTML file in TextEdit *without* it rendering the file but just showing it as source (and possibly edit it)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in TextEdit help - search for HTML

> If you open an HTML file and don’t see the HTML code, TextEdit is displaying the file in the same way a browser would. You can choose to display the file’s HTML code instead.
>
> To display the code in an HTML file:
>
> Choose File > Open.
>
> Select “Ignore rich text commands.”
>
> Locate the file and click Open.
>
> To always view the code in HTML files,
>   choose TextEdit > Preferences, click
>   “Open and Save,” and then select
>   “Ignore rich text commands in HTML
>   files” below “When Opening a File.”

So it seems you have to choose before opening the file.

Comment: Looks like you can make that a permanent setting TextEdit -> Preferences... and then click the 'Open and Save' tab and you'll see a checkbox to check to turn on 'Ignore rich text commands in HTML files' when opening a new file.

Comment: Yes I meant that you have to choose that in preferences or on opening file - so both before/on opening and not when you have it open

Comment: Thanks, great! It's a bit like choosing the way the file is encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Use the <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> key combination to render the document you're viewing as plaintext instead of WYSIWYG.

Comment: Thanks, but this just strips fonts etc. from the file, but does not show the html source (tags etc.).

Comment: Until now, that's the best I thought you could get with TextEdit.

Comment: Yes, and I appreciate it. I didn't downvote you!

Comment: @DaG: down votes don't really worry me. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like you can make that a permanent setting TextEdit -> Preferences... and then click the 'Open and Save' tab and you'll see a checkbox to check to turn on 'Ignore rich text commands in HTML files' when opening a new file.

–from old comment by Ian C

Comment: This would make a great edit to Ian’s answer above :) except it’s in the other high voted answer, no?